# emma coverage tool

Tags: emma

I am getting the following error while trying to get coverage data using emma ctl tool.

```
EMMA: processing control command sequence ...
EMMA: executing [coverage.get (C:/FD_DEV3/feddebt_sources/report/emma/coverage.ec,true,true)] ...
[EMMA v2.1, build 5320 (stable)]
emma ctl: coverage.get: RPC failure while executing [coverage.get]
Exception in thread "main" com.vladium.emma.EMMARuntimeException: coverage.get: RPC failure while executing [coverage.get]
        at com.vladium.emma.ctl.CtlProcessor._run(CtlProcessor.java:242)
        at com.vladium.emma.Processor.run(Processor.java:88)
        at com.vladium.emma.ctl.ctlCommand.run(ctlCommand.java:151)
        at emma.main(emma.java:50)
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:770)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:286)
        at com.vladium.emma.rt.rpc.Response.read(Response.java:46)
        at com.vladium.emma.rt.RTControllerClientProxy.execute(RTControllerClientProxy.java:100)
        at com.vladium.emma.ctl.CtlProcessor._run(CtlProcessor.java:231)
        ... 3 more
```

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason for it is:

The jar is not correct. Make sure that the jar is correct one.

The other error is that you did not place the jar in java/jre folder .